# Prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^4 + 2016}{x^5 + 2015x^3}\sin^3{x}dx$ is convergent but not absolutely convergent

Tags: calculus

I need to proove that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^4 + 2016}{x^5 + 2015x^3}\sin^3{x}dx$$ is convergent but not absolutely convergent. For 
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^4 + 2016}{x^5 + 2015x^3}\sin^3{x}dx$$ it's easy to see that it's convergent, but i have no idea how to work around the infinite limit with the sine function involved. Is the substitution $x = \frac{1}{t}$ a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Denote 
$$
f(x)=\frac{x^4+2016}{x^5+2015x^3}, \ a_n=\Big|\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}f(x)\sin^3(x)dx\Big|
$$ 
than
$$
\int_{\pi}^{N\pi}f(x)\sin^3(x)dx=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(-1)^na_n
$$
and the series is convergent due to Leibniz criterion.